# To put the result of a query into an array

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I've written a SQL query which return one coulmn in the result set:

`rate` has `float` type here.

```
SELECT rate 
    FROM partner.exchange
    WHERE id in (
     (SELECT max(id) 
    FROM partner.exchange 
    WHERE currency_id = 1), 
     (SELECT max(id) 
    FROM partner.exchange 
    WHERE currency_id = 2), 
     (SELECT max(id) 
    FROM partner.exchange 
    WHERE currency_id = 3)
    );
```

I need to write plpgsql function which puts that result into an array of float and returns one. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the query's result has only one column, its rows can be put into an array with:

```
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT rate FROM ...[rest of subquery]);
```

To get a particular element from this array in SQL, say the 3rd element, you may write:

```
SELECT s.x[3] FROM 
 (SELECT ARRAY(SELECT rate FROM ...[rest of subquery]) AS x)
 AS s;
```

In procedural style, this could be:

```
DECLARE
  x float[];
  ...
BEGIN
  ...
  SELECT ARRAY(SELECT rate FROM ...[rest of subquery]) INTO x;
  RETURN x[3];
END
```